# Regex prevent matching nested match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
"hello x { x {} } world"
```

I want the first pair to match but not the second group. Regex should output the following: "x { x {} }" but instead it outputs the x {} that is inside.

Can I make it so that regex only captures the parent and never the children?

A simple check like this: /x {}/g wont do. Its obvious why but im not sure what technique can be used to get around this.

Comment: While it might be possible you could do this with a change to the regex (Idunno), I could also imagine fixing it by looping through the target string in a different way, constantly tracking the first search index and moving it to the end of a pattern when one is found.

Comment: Parsing a syntax that involves stuff like nesting parentheses or brackets usually calls for a more powerful parser than what can be achieved with regular expressions.

Comment: What should be output of `"hello x { x {y {}} p{} zoo} world {again}"` ?

Comment: @anubhava "x { x {} }"

Comment: @Pointy  im aware im just not sure what so ill go with regex and do the more complex stuff using loops etc.

Comment: @Katana314 you are right. I actually like the idea.

Comment: @Asperger that string is not in the example anubhava gave as an example. I think he's just suggesting you should think about potentially deep curly brace levels. Along those lines, I would suggest you use JS logic to manually check a Regex's given container value, and maybe ignore any results that have a mismatching number of { and } values (eg, so that you ignore "x {" as a container result)

Comment: @anubhava the output should be the outer x with the entire content inside its curly braces. so x {*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use the following:

```
x\s*{.*}
```

https://regex101.com/r/VAYwYt/1

Comment: Should we use the dot operator or be as specific as possible? Or doesnt it matter performancewise?

Comment: Updated the answer @Asperger

Comment: Accepted. Both work but this one is cleaner. I wouldnt use the dot though, be as specific as possible. But hey, thats my opinion : )

Comment: Is the content limited to only a few possibilities ? If so mention it and I'll try to make it as specific as can be, for now . is the only thing I can come up with due to lack of content description/possibilities

Comment: Its ok, I can adjust it myself : ) thanks for the answer maslo

Answer (score 1):

Specific to your string this was the simplest I could generate:

```
x {?.+}
```

Reference: https://regex101.com/r/aEpueW/2

Comment: Chose yours as the answer : )

Comment: Why do all people use (.) I thought it was a performance killer?

Comment: you can omit the escaping tags \

Comment: Why is the first { optional? this would trigger on hello x asdsasadsadsa }. This would also not work on empty brackets ie: x {}

Comment: @Maslo, true. I was trying to provide the simplest answer that Asperger could build on as needed. Your revised answer is just as valid and there are several variations that will harden the result.